# Angular 2 Error no provider for String

Tags: angular, runtime-error

I am getting error in console (For Login Component Class)'No Provider for String!' but I am not using any paramenter of type String in any constructor.
I am stuck here for past 2 days and i can't figure it out.

This is my **main.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LoginService } from "./service/login.service";
import { routing } from "./app.routes";
import { Ng2Webstorage, LocalStorage, LocalStorageService } from "ng2-webstorage";
import { CookieService, ANGULAR2_COOKIE_PROVIDERS } from "angular2-cookie/core";
import { MaterializeDirective } from "angular2-materialize";
import { HomeComponent } from "./components/home/home.component";
import { LoginComponent } from "./components/login/login.component";
import { SignUpComponent } from "./components/signup/signup.component";
import { HttpModule } from "@angular/http";

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    Ng2Webstorage,
    routing,
    HttpModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    SignUpComponent
  ],
  providers: [
    LoginService,
    ANGULAR2_COOKIE_PROVIDERS,
    CookieService,
    LocalStorageService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

This is my **Login.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { LoginService } from '../../service/login.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { LocalStorageService } from 'ng2-webstorage';
import { CookieService } from 'angular2-cookie/core';


@Component({
    selector: 'login',
  templateUrl: 'login.component.html',
})
export class LoginComponent {

    constructor(private loginService: LoginService,
        private router: Router,
        private localStorage: LocalStorageService,
        private cookieService: CookieService) {
        let token = this.cookieService.get('token');

        if (token) {
            this.loginService.setToken(token);
            this.router.navigateByUrl('/text-items-list');
        }
    }

    err: any = {
        message: ""
    };

    onSubmit(form) {
        var self = this;
        self.err.message = "";
        this.loginService.login({ email: form.controls.email.value, password: form.controls.password.value })
            .subscribe(
            function (response) {
                if (response.status) {
                    if (form.controls.rememberMe.value) {
                        self.cookieService.put('token', response.token);
                    }

                    self.localStorage.clear();
                    self.localStorage.store("user", response.user);

                    self.loginService.setToken(response.token);
                    self.router.navigateByUrl('/text-items-list');
                } else {
                    self.err.essage = response.message;
                }
            }
            )
    }
}
```

I am injecting login service as well which I've created and the rest of the parameters are from dependencies.

Here is my **LoginService**

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Http, Headers } from "@angular/http";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Rx";
import { LocalStorageService, SessionStorageService } from 'ng2-webstorage';
import { CookieService } from 'angular2-cookie/core';

@Injectable()
export class LoginService {
    constructor(private http: Http, private localStorage: LocalStorageService, private cookieStorage: CookieService) { }

    private getHeaders() {
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        return headers;
    }

    setToken(encodedToken) {
        this.localStorage.store("token", encodedToken);
    }

    getToken() {
        return this.localStorage.retrieve("token");
    }

    login(credentials: { email: any, password: any }): Observable<any> {
        const postBody = JSON.stringify(credentials);
        return this.http.post('/login', postBody, {
            headers: this.getHeaders()
        }).map(res => res.json())
    }

    logout() {
        this.cookieStorage.removeAll();
        this.localStorage.clear('user');
    }

    singUp(credentials: { username: any, email: any, password: any }): Observable<any> {
        const postBody = JSON.stringify(credentials);
        return this.http.post('/login/signup', postBody, {
            headers: this.getHeaders()
        }).map(res => res.json())
    }

    checkUsernameAvailability(username: any) {
        const postBody = { username: username };
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        return this.http.post('/login/check-username-availability', postBody, {
            headers: headers
        }).map(res => res.json())
    }
}
```

This is the error which i am getting in browser's console
[error in browser's console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9MlI.png)

Comment: Could you please share complete error from browser console?

Comment: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in ./LoginComponent class LoginComponent_Host - inline template:0:0 caused by: No provider for String!(…)

Comment: Could you please share your module file ?

Comment: The given scripts seem to be correct. I think that the issue come from the loginComponent template or the host template. By the way, you don't have to declare the LocalStorageService in the module's providers block. It's declared in the Ng2Webstorage module (I m the creator).

Comment: This code seems fine. I'd start commenting out blocks of code, to narrow down the problem.